# Graphql Integration Software Similar to Postman

Tags: open-source, software-testing

I am looking for a good integration framework similar to that of newman/postman, but for graphql. I would use postman but it seems that [postman](https://github.com/postmanlabs/postman-app-support/issues/1669) doesn't quite have any support for graphql yet. I am looking for an open sourced solution that be easily executed from a terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at [Apollo](http://www.apollodata.com/) which provides open source tooling for GraphQL and some commercial tools as well. Not sure about how command line friendly they are though.